# Add whitespace to image and save file

Tags: android, image, crop

i have a image that want to add whitespace to this and save this.how i can add whitespace  to my image, i have Path of selected image from sd card.

[image]

Comment: white space to IMAGE?

Comment: i added a image for example

Comment: Keep a white background and use the padding property.

Comment: I think you can add padding to image view and create the bitmap from image view and save it as image file.

Comment: @Ahamed &  AlphaQ i want save bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a `Bitmap` at the size you want the final image to be:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then create a `Canvas` to draw to from the `Bitmap`, and draw the background color:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

Then draw the original image to the canvas:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);

int top = (original.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2;
int left = (original.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2;

canvas.drawBitmap(original, top, left, paint);
```

Finally, follow the [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) training to save this `Bitmap` to a `File`. You can use `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);` instead of `outputStream.write()` to store the `Bitmap`.

Comment: this worked best, but added a black space to my image instead of whitespace, changed to  canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN); resolved my problem